# Submit button and Radio buttons not showing any change in html UI because of JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I have a Jquery function which opens a `<a>` tag to a division (similar to old twitter login) on click of link and closes on click of the another `<div>` tag (as I have set the hide() function to `<div>`'s id).

Now with this, the four radio buttons are not showing the change in checked **status** (the user interface look, where the dot shifts, when clicked).

Also, there is a submit button which needs to be doing its work of submitting its record, doesn't create any effect when i click. I mean, when i click, it doesn't respond.

As the both radio buttons and submit form button comes in `<div>` tag, and the `<a>` is above it in a separate `div` tag.

Can anyone please tel me what can be done?

Here is that Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".check_in").click(function()
    {
        $("#check_box").show();
        return false;
    });
    $("#mainbody").click(function()
    {
        $("#check_box").hide();
        return false;
    });
})
```

The link which uses the Jquery:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="check_in"> Check</a>
    <div id="check_box">
        <form method="post" action="/ucheck/">
            <label ><i>Name</i>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></label>
            <input type="submit" value="check "/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `<div>` tag on click of which the previous block hides:

```
<div id="mainbody" >
    <table>
        <tr align="left" >
            <td><input type="radio" name="property" id="rdRent" value="rent" checked="true" /><span class="lbltext" >Rent&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="property" id="rdBuy" value="buy"/><span class="lbltext"> Buy&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="property" id="rdHotels" value="hotels"/><span class="lbltext">Hotels&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="property" id="rdPG" value="pg"/><span class="lbltext"> PG&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- Other things of form -->

                <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

(PS: Using Django)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the return false from your mainbody div like so

```
$("#mainbody").click(function()
{
    $("#check_box").hide();
});
```

The return false stops the click event from propagating and I don't think you need to do that in this instance.

http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/Vkjb6/

Comment: @Nagaraj Glad to help.  I just saw this great answer on SO that explains a bit about return false - might be handy for you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927689/when-should-i-use-return-false-in-jquery-function/5927706#5927706

Comment: Be sure to test your code after applying this solution. Return false is often useful for IE8, to prevent the entire page from refreshing.