# When should I use return false in jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, return-value

I found lots of functions like this one:

```
$(function() {
    $("body a").click(function() {
        alert(this.innerHTML);
        return false;
    });
});
```

What's the difference between `this` and `$(this)` in jquery?

They all have a line `return false;` - I don't know when I should  use `return false` in jquery function and don't know what's the use of it?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

According to [jQuery Events: Stop (Mis)Using Return False](http://web.archive.org/web/20160603125641/http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/) (archived link), returning `false` performs three tasks when called:

1. event.preventDefault();
2. event.stopPropagation();
3. Stops callback execution and returns immediately when called.

The only action needed to cancel the default behaviour is `preventDefault()`. Issuing `return false;` can create brittle code. Usually you'd want just this:

```
$("a").on( 'click', function (e) {
    // e == our event data
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And secondly "this" is a DOM element in javascript and "$(this)" is a jQuery element
that references the DOM element. Read more on the topic at [jQuery's this: demystified](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/).

Comment: Archived page as original looks not responding atm: http://web.archive.org/web/20160603125641/http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Answer (score 11):

You're clicking on an anchor, whose default behavior is to navigate somewhere.  Returning false may be an attempt to prevent the navigation and keep user on current page/view.

Answer (score 4):

In the scope of the click handler, `this` is the unwrapped DOM element. `$(this)` wraps it and returns a jQuery element. It is common practice to wrap this once and make it available within the scope as `that`, or often `$this` (prefixing variable names with $ is a convention to indicate a jQuery element).

Your example could therefore be written as

```
$(function() {
    $("body a").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        alert($this.html());
        return false;
    });
});
```