# How do I assign the result of a function into a global variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, local

I can't figure out how to assign this function's result into a global variable. I know this is a really basic thing, but can anyone help?

```
var pixel_code = null


function captureValue(){
  pixel_code = document.getElementById("baseText").value;
 return pixel_code;
}

pixel_code = captureValue();
```

Comment: What you have should work (twice ;)). Is all this code maybe inside another function?

Comment: does the baseText element have a value attribute set ?

Comment: AT @canolucas, why in the world did you edit the OP code so it was totally different? I rolled it back since you really changed it.

Comment: This code is not inside another function. When I try to console.log(pixel_code) outside of the captureValue function I get undefined. Inside of the function it outputs as I intend it to.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/UrFyF/

Comment: @epascarello the value is being set twice

Comment: @canolucas - So post a comment or answer about that. Don't "correct" the OP's code directly in the question, or the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AsNjd/3/ Here's the full spectrum of what I am trying to do

Comment: @VictorTorres - Your fiddle does work, there's just no text in the `textarea`: http://jsfiddle.net/AsNjd/4/

Comment: Victor, there are several issues with the fiddle, e.g., you shouldn't have elements within the `<head>`, but more importantly you have your JS within an `onload` handler because that is what jsfiddle does by default if you don't change it in the panel on the left - you should change that to "no wrap (head)". Regarding what you're trying to achieve, you call the function from a button click handler, but don't have other code that tries to use that global variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "global variable" ? http://www.snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable ? Or something else ?

Comment: I think my mistake was that the console.log(pixel_code) was running right when the page was loaded, but I was expecting it to log after I executed the function.

Comment: Is there a way I can make the console.log wait till I run the previous function first before it logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the jsfiddle of what you were attempting.  I see the concern.  The captureValue() function is run asynchronously, so the `console.log()` shortly after defining it doesn't yet have a value.  I've stripped and prodded the jsfiddle and come up with this working sample:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Welcome to the AdRoll SandBox</h1>

    <textarea id="baseText" style="width:400px;height:200px"></textarea><br />

    <input type="button" value="test" id="text_box_button" onclick="captureValue()"/>
    <input type="button" value="get" id="text_box_button2" onclick="getValue()"/>
    <script>
var pixel_code = null;

function captureValue(){
    pixel_code = document.getElementById("baseText").value;
    return false;
}

function getValue() {
    alert(pixel_code);
    return false;
}
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I added a second button.  Type in the textbox, push "test" (to set the value), then push "get" to get the value of the global variable.

Here's the same sample that uses jQuery and a closure to avoid the global variable:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Welcome to the AdRoll SandBox</h1>

    <textarea id="baseText" style="width:400px;height:200px"></textarea><br />

    <input type="button" value="test" id="text_box_button" />
    <input type="button" value="get" id="text_box_button2" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pixel_code = null;

    $("#text_box_button").click(function (){
        pixel_code = document.getElementById("baseText").value;
        return false;
    });

    $("#text_box_button2").click(function () {
        alert(pixel_code);
        return false;
    });
});
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. One question, why 'return false'?

Comment: `return false` avoids the default behavior.  In this case, default behavior isn't a whole lot.  But switch the `<input type="button"` for an `<a href="` and you'll accidentally navigate to a different page or reload this page if you don't have the `return false`.  See http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927689/when-should-i-use-return-false-in-jquery-function which will chastise me for `return false` in favor of `preventDefault()`.

Comment: Awesome, good lessons for me. The help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Glad it worked out so well for you.  Thank you for accepting my answer.  Welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You're reusing pixel_code in and out of the function, which is not a great pattern, but the code you show should work as expected.  What error are you seeing?  What code surrounds this code that you're not showing?  Could all this perhaps be nested inside another function?  (Thanks @JosephSilver for the nod.)

Comment: This is not an answer. You should post it as a comment.

Comment: if I run console.log(pixel_code) or document.write(pixel_code) outside of the function I only get undefined. Inside of the function it works fine.

Comment: Previously you had `pixel_code = captureValue();` and the function had `return ...`.  If that's the case, even with the reused var you should get the correct result.  Perhaps you could create an example on jsfiddle.com

Comment: @robrich I posted the jsfiddle on the comment stream under the question

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle.  (I missed it the first go-round because I had to click "show more comments".  Silly me.)  See my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the page reloads, your variable will be reset to it's initial state.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
var pixel_code='';

function captureValue(){
  return document.getElementById("baseText").value;
}

function getValueBack()
{
    pixel_code = captureValue();
    //alert(pixel_code); /* <----- uncomment to test -----<< */
}
```