# Why does an alert redirect my page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Why does everytime I put an alert to my ajaxform the page redirects to its php script? but when I remove the alert the ajax doesn't redirect it. I don't want my page to redirect to its php script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           $("#save").click(function(){
           $("#f1").ajaxForm({
                    alert("Submit Successful!");
                    });//ajaxform
    });
});
```

Comment: use return false; after alert

Comment: Because that is not the right syntax. try using a callback

Answer (score 3):

**Replace**

```
$("#save").click(function(){
```

**with**

```
$("#save").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
```

pass event as argument and use `event.preventDefault()` so page will not be redirect.

[`Official Document`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Answer (score 3):

You're not using several things properly. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#save").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //cancel default action (not strictly necessary...)

        $("#f1").ajaxForm(function() { //N.B. 'function() ' added - before it was an object!
            alert("Submit Successful!");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

trying stopping the default event behavior.

```
 $("#save").click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`return false`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927689/when-should-i-use-return-false-in-jquery-function): to stop the request to server

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#save").click(function () {
         $("#f1").ajaxForm(function(){
             alert("Submit Successful!");
             return false;//add return false to stop the request to server
         }); //ajaxform
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the normal behavior (if the clicked element is an anchor tag pointing to another page): you click a link and it redirects your page.
If you want to use that link as a button and bind a certain action to it, you should definitely stop the normal behavior of the link: prevent it from redirecting the page.
This is achievable in many ways, but the best one (at least from a semantic point of view) is to call the [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method on the actual click event:

```
$('a').on('click', function(event){
    // prevents the normal behavior of this "click" action
    // in this case, it prevents the link from changing the url
    event.preventDefault();

    //.. your logic here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `preventDefault()` or `return false;`.

```
$("#save").click(function(e) {
    $("#f1").ajaxForm({
        alert("Submit Successful!");
    });//ajaxform
    e.preventDefault();
    //or
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Using `return false;` is actually not the correct way to halt an event (or it's at least very destructive): http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Answer (score -1):

Try this use preventDefault()

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#save").click(function(e){
       //Stay in the same page
       e.preventDefault();

        $("#f1").ajaxForm({

            alert("Submit Successful!");

        });//ajaxform

    });

});
```