# jQuery - Form still submits with return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

http://jsfiddle.net/QsTfc/

For some odd reason the form keeps submitting even though I am returning false. I have tried:

```
$("#submitEdit").submit(function() {
    return false;
});

$("#submitEdit").submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

And this is what I currently have:

```
<script>

$('a').click(function() {
    var parentId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    var child = $("#" + parentId).children().eq(1);
    var childText = $(child).text();
    $(child).html('<form action="<?php echo URL; ?>user/changeSettings/' + parentId + '" method="POST" id="submitEdit"><input type="text" name="' + parentId + '" value="' + childText + '" /></form>');
    console.log(childText);
});

$("#submitEdit").on("submit", function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    alert(data);
    $.post(url, data, function(returned) {
        $(parentId + "Field").html(returned);
        return false;
    });
    return false;
});

</script>
```

Comment: Assuming that the missing double quotes in the excerpt is a typo. Otherwise that is reason enough for your form to go through with the submission.

Comment: Add a `return false` in `$("a").click` handler too.

Comment: @IonicăBizău - Not needed. Returning `false` from `onsubmit` is sufficient to stop default form submission.

Comment: There was initially a return false in the anchor handler but I got rid of it to see if that was somehow the problem.

Comment: @Qualisasa Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Ionică Bizău I have added the jsfiddle.

Comment: @Qualisasa You need delegation. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your jsfiddle demo your form is added dinamically. So, you have to use delegation:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#submitEdit", function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    alert(data);
    $.post(url, data, function(returned) {
        $(parentId + "Field").html(returned);
        return false;
    });
    return false;
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QsTfc/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to put your event parameter in your call back function

```
$("#submitEdit).submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

and try this:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#submitEdit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    alert(data);
    $.post(url, data, function(returned) {
        $(parentId + "Field").html(returned);
        return false;
    });
});
```

when to use return false and when to use  event.preventDefault().
you can take a look for this question:
[When  should I use return false in jquery function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927689/when-should-i-use-return-false-in-jquery-function)

Comment: `return false` = stopPropagation() & preventDefault()

Comment: This didn't succeed, I appreciate your help though!