# my ajax keeps refreshing the whole page instead of the div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax form and I want to reload the div instead of the whole page, but it isn't working.

This is my handling.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#guideForm').submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../includes/handling.php',
            data: $(this).serialize()
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#guide').load(document.URL + ' #guide');
        })
        return false;   
    }); 
});
```

this is my handling.php:

```
if ($_POST['guide']) {
    $settings->addGuide($_POST['guide']); 
}
```

**EDIT:** 
Formcodes:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h2>test title</h2>
  <p class="guids">This is a test text.</p>
  <form method="post" id="guideForm">
     <input name="guide" value="1" style="positon:absolute; display:none;">
     <button class="btn btn-primary">Got it!</button>       
  </form>         
</div>
```

Can someone help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you can cancel the default action of form by https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault

Comment: can you share your form codes as well

Answer (score 0):

You should try `e.preventDefault()`

```
$('#guideForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // added this line and an argument 'e' to the function
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../includes/handling.php',
            data: $(this).serialize()
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#guide').load(document.URL + ' #guide');
        })
        return false;   
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop the page from submitting you need to prevent the default behavior of the event i.e. to submit the form.

Your page keeps reloading because after your request DOM submits the form. And, as default behavior, Your form submits itself on the same page as you haven't specified a action param.

So, there are multiple ways of doing this.

**i).** Stop the JS event from propagating by using the method `preventDefault()` of event object.

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#guideForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //stop default behaviour
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../includes/handling.php',
            data: $(this).serialize()
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#guide').load(document.URL + ' #guide');
        })
        return false;   
    }); 
});
```

This is the most official way of doing this.

**ii).** You can change your submit button/input to a simple button and bind the ajax with `onClick` event.

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#fakeSubmitButton').click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../includes/handling.php',
        data: $(this).serialize()
    })
    .done(function(data){
        $('#guide').load(document.URL + ' #guide');
    })
    return false;   
}); 
});
```

**iii).** You can define `javascript:void(0)` as your form's action attribute. This will automatically prevent form from submitting.

**iv).** By returning `false` from the event handler. Which you are currently doing. It is strange it is not working as jQuery doc itself says:

> we can cancel the submit action by calling `.preventDefault()` on the event object or by returning `false` from our handler.

Maybe the following post can help you: 
[jQuery - Form still submits with return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657272/jquery-form-still-submits-with-return-false)

Also check the answer of Chen-Tsu Lin in the above post. It is given a link for when you should not use `return false`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And the return false? That should stop the refresh, right?

Comment: @web-stars Yes added that part just now. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Use e.preventDefault();

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#guideForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../includes/handling.php',
            data: $(this).serialize()
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#guide').load(document.URL + ' #guide');
        })
        return false;   
    }); 
});
```

Comment: And the return false? That should stop the refresh, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#guideForm').submit()
```

The above jquery statement would by default submit the fold which would essentially reload the code. If you do not want this to happen,

add the following

```
event.preventDefault();
```

This would prevent the submit of the form and execute the code in the function

Comment: there's already a "return false;" inside the submit event..so that should stop the page from reloading

Comment: @parpar I agree the return false would stop the execution, but then all the lines of code after return false would not be executed, If you need the subsequent lines to be executed you would need to use `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: that's why in his code, the "return false" is in last line..which means everything else will be executed, then prevent page from reloading

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an error in your js that's why it doesn't execute as expected, have you checked if you get any error? Maybe it's because you don't have a termination on your $.ajax function.. try adding ";" terminator.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#guideForm').submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../includes/handling.php',
            data: $(this).serialize()
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#guide').load(document.URL + ' #guide');
        });

        return false;   
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **e.preventDefault()**; to stop the default behavior of submit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#guideForm').submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault(); //stop default behaviour
       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
            url: '../includes/handling.php',
            data: $(this).serialize()
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#guide').load(document.URL + ' #guide');
        })
        return false;   
    }); 
});
```

Comment: And the return false? That should stop the refresh, right?