# jQuery ‘val("")’ not working on bind ‘paste’ to make changes in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make change on input field using jQuery in such order when the user pasted a text which starting with **'0'** character. In other words if for example the user pasted **'0'** it will be changed to **'1'**.

My entire HTML code is like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#amount").bind("paste", function(evt) {
        var pastedData = evt.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
        if (pastedData.charAt(0).length != 0 && pastedData.charAt(0) == '0') {
            $("#amount").val("1");
            alert("you entered " + pastedData + "; but we can't change it to 1!");
        };
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

paste 0 in this field. it shall be changed to 1, but the result will be 10!<br>
<input type="text" id="amount" placeholder="enter amount...">

</body>
</html>
```

But the problem is, when I paste **'0'** it will not change to **'1'**; it will be changed to **'10'**. Or if you enter **'00000'** it will be **'100000'**. In other words the code just prepend **'1'** to my pasted text.

Now can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Just FYI, `bind()` is deprecated. Use [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop the paste event ussing [preventDefault:](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#amount").bind("paste", function(evt) {
        var pastedData = evt.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
        if (pastedData.charAt(0).length != 0 && pastedData.charAt(0) == '0') {
            $("#amount").val("1");
            evt.preventDefault();
            alert("you entered 0; but we can't change it to 1!");
        };
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
paste 0 in this field. it shall be changed to 1, but the result will be 10!<br>
<input type="text" id="amount" placeholder="enter amount...">
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are in the paste event, value is first assigned as 1, then you're not stopping the event from pasting hence whatever is in the clipboard gets pasted. You need to use `evt.preventDefault()` which will stop the event and from the pasted data remove the first `0` using `pastedData.slice(1)` if you want to use it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#amount").bind("paste", function(evt) {
    var pastedData = evt.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    if (pastedData.charAt(0).length != 0 && pastedData.charAt(0) == '0') {
      evt.preventDefault();
      $("#amount").val("1");// + pastedData.slice(1));
      alert("you entered 0; but we can't change it to 1!");
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
paste 0 in this field. it shall be changed to 1, but the result will be 10!<br>
<input type="text" id="amount" placeholder="enter amount...">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(this).attr('value', '1');
```

instead of this line :

```
$("#amount").val("1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to [`return false`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5927706/1243247) at the end of the `if` statement inside the bind function. By returning `false` you prevent the default behaviour and stop propagation, avoiding then the pasting of `0` that was on the waiting list to be added after `1`.

Check your exemple here, it is working like you want and I just added `return false`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#amount").bind("paste", function(evt) {
        var pastedData = evt.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
        if (pastedData.charAt(0).length != 0 && pastedData.charAt(0) == '0') {
            $("#amount").val("1");
            alert("you entered 0; but we can't change it to 1!");
            return false;
        };
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

paste 0 in this field. it shall be changed to 1, but the result will be 10!<br>
<input type="text" id="amount" placeholder="enter amount...">
```