# How can I add a self-referring onclick event to every <a>?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick, href

I have a single page app, for which I'd want to make sure link clicks don't get processed in the regular way, but are passed to my router instead. I therefore have the currently perfectly working menu code (where `goto` changes the HTML and returns false):

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/framework" onclick="return goto(this);">Home</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="/framework/register" onclick="return goto(this);">Register</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="/framework/login" onclick="return goto(this);">Log In</a>
```

Since every link gets the same `onclick` attribute anyway, is there some way I can write my links as

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/framework">Home</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="/framework/register">Register</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="/framework/login">Log In</a>
```

like I would on a non-SPA website, and have the `onclick` event be applied globally?

Comment: My earlier statement was wrong, `$('a').onclick('return goto(this);');` does work, so that makes this quite a silly questions, apologies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a click event listener.

```
$('a').click(function(e){
   goto(this);
   e.preventDefault();//don't navigate away
   /*we can't use return goto(this) because returning false in a jQuery event handler 
      also stops event propagation */
});
```

If your anchor elements are dynamic, you can use event delegation.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){
   goto(this);
   e.preventDefault();//don't navigate away
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "we can't use return goto(this) because returning false in a jQuery event handler also stops event propagation"? That's interesting, I was not aware this could yield any problems.

Comment: @user1111929 `return false` in a jQuery event handler is equivalent to `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: @user1111929 See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927689/when-should-i-use-return-false-in-jquery-function

Comment: That is really interesting, and I was doing it wrong on form submits as well, so this has been valuable to me. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this?

```
element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  // Do your things
})
```

Comment: `e` is not an *Event Binder* - it's an Object argument provided by the `addEventListener` method. It's not *bound* to anything.